# Is there a default vscode backup or file recovery system?

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, recovery

Trying to recover mysteriously deleted files in VScode. These files disappeared while i was tabbed out of the application. I want to know if there is any way to get them back.

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Machine on a windows 10 computer. On the VM I had VScode editing scripts on the shared folder between the VM and my PC. I tabbed out of the VM and when I tabbed back the only two scripts I had open were gone. The two files were of different naming and in different folders but both were gone. No other files, even ones in the same folders, were deleted as far as I could tell. The files were absent when observing from both the windows and VM file explorers.

I closed the VM and restarted my computer. The files were still gone. Is there any default backup system in VScode or rewind system in VirtualBox that can fix this? I've lost almost a month's worth of work here so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71457856/5440638

Answer (score 0):

Yes. VSCode calls it "Hot exit".

from [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit):

> ### Hot Exit
>
> [...] all backups are stored in the following folders for standard install locations:
>
> - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\Backups`
> - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups`
> - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/Backups`

More details in my answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71457856/5440638