# restore previous version of a saved file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, backup

TL;DR: I have saved a file, I need the previous version. What do I do?

I had had a lot of code, cut them (`ctrl+x`), and wanted to paste them somewhere else that VS code crashed. I opened it again, copy some other lines, and BOOM! I can't access the first cut lines. Is there any way I can have them back?

Notes:

1. I didn't commit them.
2. Because of that continues crash, I installed/uninstalled VScode 2-3 times, even installed `VS-insiders` **BUT** I saved the **PREVIOUS** data files like `.vscode` folder in `C:\Users\User` or `Code` folder under `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Code` directory, for all previous VScode installations (All are for today).
3. I read links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635755/visual-studio-code-backup-mechanics), but my files are saved. They aren't saved in that `backup` folder.
4. VS is configured to autosave files (after a delay), so I don't press `ctrl+s` manually.
5. I have git enabled, does that help? The file is staged btw.

Comment: you can try to use `git reflog`, read the doc pages to find which "commit" to use, or use a versioning file system like VMS

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solution is in [Local History](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830780/1772898) and [Timeline View](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view). It does not need version control. VSCode internally save file in `.config/code/Backups` in different scenarios.

If you want to go back to one of the previous states of a file, you have to use **Timeline View** to check the file's **Local History**. When you find the file, right click on it and press `Restore Contents`

[image]

Here is a screenshot of **Timeline View** of a file in my machine. However, your User Interface may not be organized like mine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a life saver. I never knew vs code implicitly did this.